# Mongoose has no mg_create_server function?

Tags: c, api, include, mongoose-web-server

I'm following the [Mongoose Embedding Guide](https://docs.cesanta.com/Embed.shtml) and I get the error:

```
error: ‘mg_create_server’ was not declared in this scope
     struct mg_server *server = mg_create_server(NULL, NULL);
```

This is copied verbatim from the embedding guide.

Looking in [mongoose.h](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/mongoose.h), [there is no `mg_create_server` anywhere to be found](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mg_create_server)! Neither in that latest version, nor [5.1](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mongoose/downloads), nor [4.1](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mongoose/downloads) (from the google code archives).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mg_create_server` apparently exists in [version 5.6](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/tree/5.6). Version 6.0 (the latest) has changed the API, and they didn't update their embedding guide. [Here](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/examples/restful_server/restful_server.c) is an example of a RESTful server with the latest version of Mongoose. [Here](https://docs.cesanta.com/mongoose/) are the latest API docs.